# Full address list for city Radebeul (Germany)

Tags: geospatial, germany, address

For a city of [Radebeul](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Radebeul/@51.1156981,13.5730842,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4709d1bdaf338d05:0x421b1cb4288d620!8m2!3d51.1115648!4d13.6493707), located in the federal state Saxony in Germany, I am looking for a list with all addresses, something like

```
id | Street                | Nr  | PLZ   | City
1  | Meißner Straße        | 266 | 01445 | Radebeul
2  | Heinrich-Zille-Straße | 25  | 01445 | Radebeul
.  | ...                   | ... | 01445 | Radebeul
```

What are those options/sources of data?

I somehow think about deploying [overpass-turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) or [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) as was suggested in this thread [Return all elements associated with address - Overpass API](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/62048/return-all-elements-associated-with-address-overpass-api?). But perhaps there are other free/open solutions which will somehow differ from OSM data basic.

There was also an idea to extract all points (keeping in mind a certain category/amenity) and all buildings as polygons from OpenStreetMap (e.g. using QGIS, as described in this thread [Searching and Downloading OpenStreetMap Data](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html)), making geocentoids out of buildings, then defining `($x, $y)` for each building feature  and each point, and finally put all that coordinates into one common list and proceed via geocoding engine, like [HERE Geocoding API](https://developer.here.com/signup/geocoding) or [Python Geocoder](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder) by means of reverse geocoding.

I am aware of this question is partially related to the *"geocoding"* topic but I am wondering if I can somehow extract the full list of all addresses, something like a reference list from the geocoding library/solution. Unluckily some resources for Germany were demolished, found in this topic [Mass Geocoding Requests for Germany?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91726/mass-geocoding-requests-for-germany).

Unfortunately, the [Radebeul city portal](https://www.radebeul.de/Einwohnerportal/Dokumente/Pl%C3%A4ne+_+Karten.html) does not provide such data. Additionally, the data from [Deutsche Post](https://umziehen.de/) probably costs much money.

Comment: Nice question. Not sure if the data would come from anyone but the municipality (zB [Stadt Zürich](https://data.stadt-zuerich.ch/dataset/adressen)), so you may have to ask (bug) them.

Comment: Thank you for a hint. I will ask the Stadtverwaltungsamt. Let's see what they gonna reply. Data fro Zürich looks wonderful

Comment: Something really not optimal but doable is to use Google Maps API varying LAT and LONG, if you define a reasonable area and a small LAT LONG variation you will get all addresses. However, it will take time and you'll have to pay for the exceeding requests.

Comment: @GustavoMorais, if I got you correct you suggest deploying [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start), am I right? Regarding the varying tuple `{lat, long}` what should be the step in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are 8596 data records with addresses available for the city of Radebeul.

The Adress data for For [Saxony (Free State of Saxony)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxony) in Germany can be downloaded in `zip`-format from the following link:

https://www.geodaten.sachsen.de/downloadbereich-hauskoordinaten-4172.html

The inside of the archive includes several files:

[image: zip_archive]

A file with addresses `"adressen.txt"` looks as following:

[image: addresses]

More about the structure of txt-file with house coordinates can be found in the PDF document attached below.

Columns (#12 and #13) that represent coordinates are projected in [EPSG:25833](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-33n/).

---

**References:**

- [Free address data providers for Germany](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180200/free-address-data-providers-for-germany/361029#361029)

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned in the comments, but in addition to google maps geocoding API, you can use [Nominatim](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/) geocoding from [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org).

Here's an example query based on latitude and longitude:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=51.108236%2C+13.631143

[image]

which resolves to this address:

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=172430942

```
Address Tags    
    Radebeul (city)
    266 (housenumber)
    01445 (postcode)
    Meißner Straße (street)
```

---

Nominatim has an official [API](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/), and some [unofficial ones](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Alternatives_.2F_Third-party_providers), so in theory you could discretize lat/long pairs on a grid, and the generate N queries, and store results.

Or, you can install your [own instance of Nominatim](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/). And then figure out how to extract all addresses within a Polygon from the bulk data. (I'm sure it's a solved problem.)